# How to count the push Notifications and display them on the home screen app icon

Tags: android

How to count the push Notifications  and display them on the home screen app icon

public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
}

Comment: I insert mine into a database and count the rows.

Answer (score 0):

You can't display notification numbers in the App Icon.  You can't change this icon at run-time.  Besides, this is an iOS paradigm (displaying the number of notifications in the icon), so you shouldn't do this on Android anyway even if it was possible.

Answer (score 0):

You can't. Android doesn't have any analogous to iOS's "badge count". My wife's Samsung displays Facebook notification count, but that's something that's built into TouchWiz and perhaps a special Facebook addition for Samsung phones.